# Ubuntu LiveCD logged off

Tags: live-cd, logout

A few times the Ubuntu LiveCD logged me out (the logon screen prompted for a user/password) when I was using some applications and I had to restart the OS. Can anyone tell me de default user/password..

Comment: You should(not must but still) set one while installing Ubuntu so that you dont face this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Username : **ubuntu**

Password: **keep it blank and try to login**

Comment: i'll try it next time.. i think that i forgot to leave it blank :(

Comment: this does not work

Answer (score 0):

A blank username and password worked for me on an Ubuntu 12.10 live environment.

Comment: I've reworded for clarity; please feel free to edit further if I didn't capture what you were trying to express. Are you sure about the *blank username*? Can you provide details about the situation under which you were able to authenticate with a blank username? Are you sure it's not just that you *didn't have to select or enter a username* (but only a password, which was blank)?

Answer (score 0):

I was doing some backups using Kubuntu 8.04 LiveCD and locked myself out. Blank password did not work and neither did any other I tried (ubuntu, kubuntu, demo, ...). Username was ubuntu. Then I found [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/foundations-bugs/2011-October/045794.html):

> I switched to terminal with Ctrl+Alt+F1... F2 whatever.  and there I changed password for current user with passwd command. 
>     And again came back to Ctrl+Alt+F7 and entered the password which I have reset.

Current password, asked by passwd, was blank even though login screen did not accept it directly.